# SDL2 плавное движение квадрата

Tags: c++, алгоритм, sdl2

**SDL2**.
Есть квадрат, который движется в левую сторону по 1 пикселю. Все это происходит в бесконечном цикле. Как увеличить скорость движения квадрата, не изменяя шага. То-есть, можно двигать его по 2, 4, 100 пикселей, за одну итерацию, но тогда теряется плавность. Можно еще установить SDL_Delay на большее значение, но тогда теряется частота кадров. Какой способ еще есть?

Comment: Скорость = расстояние / время. Для увеличения скорости надо увеличить расстояние и/или уменьшить время. Без акцента на конкретные технологии. Расстояние, как я понял, фиксировано (размер изображения), значит надо уменьшать время. Т.е. задержку м/у шагами бесконечного цикла.

Comment: Каким способом эту задержку изменить? В Бесконечном цикле также происходят другие операции: рисование других объектов, проверка нажатия клавиш. Если замедлять весь цикл - замедлятся и другие операции.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку центральная часть квадрата при каждом его перемещении стоит на месте, то можно перерисовывать только левую и правую границы квадрата. Т.е., выводя один прямоугольник 2xN на левой стороне квадрата, мы перерисовываем левую сторону квадрата (если квадрат без теней, горизонтальных градиентов, сложных текстур и тому подобных прибамбасов), а другим прямоугольником 2xN аналогично перерисовываем правую сторону.

Если сторона квадрата больше 4 пикселей, то возможен выигрыш в скорости.

Есть надежда, что проблему синхронизации движения прямоугольников решать не придётся.

Comment: Квадрат з текстурами, а задачу я описал попроще. Но спасибо за идею. Главная проблема в том, то движение напрямую зависит от FPS. Так как SDL_Delay уставлен на значение, что бы FPS был равен 30 кадров в секунду. Если скорость равна, например, 8 пикселям, за секунду, он проходит 8*30=240px в секунду. необходимо убрать эту привязку в FPS.

Comment: @Олег Кубин Насчёт привязки - само собой, а вот с простыми текстурами можно расправиться тоже, если по ходу дела менять прямоугольники.

Answer (score 1):

В бесконечном цикле не делайте задержек, а просто прибавляйте к переменной 1 через определенное время.
Например

```
    #include <ctime>
    //...
    int x=1000;
    clock_t start = clock();
    while(...){
        if(clock()-start >=500){
            start=clock();
            x--;
        }
    //Дальше отображение квадрата
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Event event;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;

SDL_FRect person;

int main(){
    window=SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 800, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    renderer=SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    const Uint8 *key=SDL_GetKeyboardState(0);

    person.x=0;
    person.y=0;
    person.w=100;
    person.h=100;

    while(window!=NULL){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if(event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                window=NULL;
            if(event.key.keysym.scancode==SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE)
                window=NULL;
        }

        if(key[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
            person.x+=0.05;

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 250, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderFillRectF(renderer, &person);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно убрать привязку к FPS. Сделать это можно следующим образом:

1. Рассчитываем `deltaTime (это время с последнего кадра)
2. Умножаем шаг перемещения на `deltaTime`.

`deltaTime` расчитывается следующим образом:

```
private void RenderLoop()
{
    bool cap = Settings.FPS > 0; // ограничение по FPS
    var timer_fps = new Timer();

    ulong now_counter = SDL.SDL_GetPerformanceCounter(); //получаем счетчик

    while (_loop)  //цикл рендера
    {
        timer_fps.Start(); 

        ulong last_counter = now_counter; // начинаем считать разницу
        now_counter = SDL.SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        Time.DeltaTime = (float)(now_counter - last_counter) / SDL.SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency(); //расчет deltaTime

        SDL.SDL_RenderClear(_instance);

        //render
        
        SDL.SDL_RenderPresent(_instance);

        if(cap && ( timer_fps.GetTicks() < 1000 / Settings.FPS ) ) //ограничиваем FPS
        {
            SDL.SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / Settings.FPS  ) - timer_fps.GetTicks() );
        }
    }
}
```

Далее, делаем что-то вроде `Sprite.Transform.TranslateX(10 * Time.DeltaTime);` и получаем плавное движение независимо от FPS.